# page wrapper with max-width breaks layout on zoom in

Tags: css

I have all my pages in one main div called "wrapper", and it is set to `max-width: 1000px`, which I need in order to make my site responsive.

The problem is, if I zoom in the layout breaks because of the `max-width` property. If i just set it to `width` instead of `max-width` it doesn't break (which makes sense), but I simply want to know if there is a solution for this ?

So, can I have max-width on the `#wrapper` without breaking the layout on zoom in?

Answer (score 0):

Try using ems instead of pixels for your max width.